# One of the answers to my question is deleted? Why?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17402444/996493) yesterday and I got 3 answers. One of the answer is near to my need. But toady that answer is deleted? why? I commented on that specific answer to optimize it to some extent. Where can I get that answer?

Comment: The owner of the answer deleted it.

Comment: The answer was deleted by owner 15 hours ago

Comment: The owner has since undeleted it, with the comment "Since you said it wasn't working as intended and there were other better answers, i deleted it." It appears there was a simple misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was deleted by the owner 15 hours ago.

> why ?

I don't know the specific reason for it. Maybe the owner didn't find it suitable for you, or maybe he saw that you have another 2 answers.

> Where can I get that answer?

Here's what was in the answer:

> You were close.
>
> ```
> select a.farmer_id, a.farmer_name,
>  (select sum(tons_supplied)
>             from sugar_distribution b
>             where b.farmer_id = a.farmer_id
>             and b.season_cd = 2) as t2006,
>  (select sum(tons_supplied)
>             from sugar_distribution b
>             where b.farmer_id = a.farmer_id
>             and b.season_cd = 8) as t2012
> from farmer_dir a;
> ```
>
> Sample fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9fe1/6)

Comment: @Mallesh, when you finally solve your problem, be sure to post your solution as the answer to the question, assuming none of the other answers are helpful. This will ensure your question is useful to others and that someone else with the same problem won't have to come to Meta to find the answer. ;)  Hope this helps!